# linq to sql , model first development?

Tags: database, linq, linq-to-sql, database-design

Is is it possible to use l2s in model first approach?
Here's the think i want to achieve:
I want to write my app in TDD manner, so I want to write some domain specific objects first and then base on that generate database model. 
One solution is to l2s as DAL but and map linq generated entities to my custom domain objects(I Rob C. in Storefront app did), but i would like to use l2s objects directly
Other solution is to use  [T4 Toolbox: LINQ to SQL schema generator](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/05/t4-toolbox-linq-to-sql-schema-generator/)  but it is based on visual team system IDE, which I don't have access to

Last solution i found is to use [Close2Poco](http://www.codeplex.com/Close2Poco)

Have you tried any of this solutions ?
Is it easy to achieve with l2s?

P.S.
Sorry for my english

Comment: This blog post by Ian Cooper may be of interest to you: [Being Ignorant with LINQ to SQL](http://iancooper.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!844BD2811F9ABE9C!397.entry)

Answer (score 0):

Not with the current version.  Visual Studio 2010 will support this.  There's currently a preview release available from Microsoft here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx